# Confused by changed API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I worked with rails around the year ago. Now I get the new version of Rails and I am a bit confused.

Where is my script/server and script/generate. I finded [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and as I see I need use 'rails' command now.

Is it version 3 changes? Is there a document which describe all such changes. Is there a good book corresponding to new version Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is described in the [Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html) of 3.0 that those scripts have been replaced by rails c (console) and rails s (server). It's pretty straight forward and very comfortable in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/rails3  gives you screencasts of major changes in rails3

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of information about the changes made for Rails 3, available from the Ruby on Rails website at http://www.rubyonrails.org. In particular, check out the screencasts section. Also, check http://guides.rubyonrails.org as that is full of detail about the changed API.